# echo is not printing the escape character since php 7

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with echo and the escape (`\e`), I want to print a directory name on the screen that is like  `t:\test\error` now as `\e` is seen as the escape character it removes it and echo shows `t:\testrror`

simple PHP code :

```
$done = "t:\test\error" ;
echo $done;
```

This seems to be an issue since PHP 7 as it worked in 5.x, no change using htmlspecialchars or htmlentities

Any ideas?

Comment: According to https://eval.in/721604  this shouldn't have worked in PHP 5 either. Are you sure you didn't switch single quotes for double quotes at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$done = "t:\\test\\error" ;
```

Comment: @Robvk Please *accept* the answer if it resolved your issue. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Personally not a big fan of "Try this" answers and are considered as being of very low quality. There is a reason for using this type of syntax.